# Configure Fluent Nhibernate with NHibernate.Caches.MemCached

Tags: configuration, fluent-nhibernate, memcached, castle-windsor

I am trying to configure Fluent NHibernate with MemCache but I get the following error. I am using MVC5+CastleWindsor+FluentNHibernate+UOW

`private static ISessionFactory CreateNhSessionFactory()
        {
            var connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AESConnect"].ConnectionString;
            return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connStr))
                .Cache(c=>c.ProviderClass(typeof(NHibernate.Caches.MemCache.MemCacheProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName).UseSecondLevelCache())
                .ExposeConfiguration(e=>e.SetProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache","true"))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HotelsMap))))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
        }`

Error:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    Memcached.ClientLibrary.SockIOPool.Initialize() in
>   C:\devroot\memcacheddotnet\trunk\clientlib\src\clientlib\SockIOPool.cs:441
>   NHibernate.Caches.MemCache.MemCacheProvider.Start(IDictionary`2
>   properties) +3627
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping
>   mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners) +1098
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +181
>   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() +73
>
> [FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration
>   was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons
>   collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>
> ]    FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
>   +117    AESRepositories.Installers.AESInstaller.CreateNhSessionFactory() ....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be a problem with the server list not being initialised.

This is from the SockIOPool.cs file:

```
/// The pool must be initialized prior to use. This should typically be early on
/// in the lifecycle of the application instance.
```

The same file has an initialisation example like this:

```
/// String[] serverlist = {"cache0.server.com:12345", "cache1.server.com:12345"};
///
/// SockIOPool pool = SockIOPool.GetInstance();
/// pool.SetServers(serverlist);
/// pool.Initialize();
```

Maybe you are missing the configuration of the connection pool, or maybe you are not initialising it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I feel I am missing a big step in my setup. I dont see SockIOPool.cs file. So I am going to find out what I am missing and I will reply back here. Thank you again for your response and please bookmark this post :) I will have some questions coming soon :) Thanks.